# Set Theory: Proving (A∩C)∪(A∩B)∪(B'∩C)=(A∩B)∪(B'∩C) algebraically only.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First, let me just say that I'm an amateur mathematician. I'd like to prove that (A∩C)∪(A∩B)∪(B'∩C) is equal to (A∩B)∪(B'∩C) without using methods like induction or showing that (A∩C) ⊆ (A∩B)∪(B'∩C). I want to know if it can be done algebraically, and if it can be, how to do it. I'm familiar with most of the properties of intersection and union.

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid the proof that uses the fact that $(A\cap C)\subseteq (A\cap B)\cup (B'\cap C)$?  It seems to be the cleanest proof available.  Induction doesn't really make sense to talk about here, noone would use an induction proof for this.  (As for how to prove that statement, suppose $x\in (A\cap C)$.  So $x\in A$ and $x\in C$.  Now, we know that either $x\in B$ or $x\not\in B$.  If $x\in B$ then $x\in (A\cap B)$.  Else if $x\not\in B$ then $x\in (B'\cap C)$.  Hence regardless which case we are in $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (B'\cap C)$)

Comment: In terms of "algebraic manipulation," that previous proof could be reworded as rewriting the furthest left term as $(A\cap C) = (A\cap C)\cap (B\cup B') = (A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap B'\cap C)$, and then using the fact that $(X\cap Y)\cup Y = Y$

Comment: Is $B'$ the same as not $B$? I don't like proofs in set theory, it is just alot of text :D. What i like to do is, to first draw a Venn-Diagram of all sets with largest amounts of intersection between the circles(e.g. A has overlap with B and C, and so do the others have overlap with each other.. Then i give names to every single patch that is generated by the venn diagram. These patches are disjunctive! Then i rewrite my sets using a union of the disjunctive patches. The rest is quite algorithmic.

Comment: When I would like to avoid using the fact that (A∩C)⊆(A∩B)∪(B′∩C)

Comment: Sorry about that, I pressed enter in hope for a newline character (please forgive me, as that was my first post)

Comment: When I first came across this problem, I wasn't aware of the fact that (A∩C)⊆(A∩B)∪(B′∩C), and was wondering if that were the only way to prove that (A∩C) is unnecessary. I'm also wondering if there's a way to prove this without expanding (A∩C) to (A∩B∩C)∪(A∩B'∩C). If not, how do you know intuitively that you will end up proving the original question by making this particular expansion? I saw that it would work after I read that message, but I don't know how you knew to do that.

Comment: $\newcommand{\R}{\Rightarrow}\newcommand{\Q}{A\mathbin\triangleleft B\mathbin\triangleright C}$Note that $\;(A\cap B)\cup(B'\cap C)\;=\;(A\cup B')\cap(B\cup C)\;$. One could write $\;\Q\;$ for either side. Notice that this is essentially the set level version of the logic expression $\;(P\land Q)\lor(\lnot Q\land R)\;$ or $\;(Q\R P)\land(\lnot Q\R R)\;$, which one could abbreviate as $\;P\text{ if }Q\text{ else }R\;$. The OP's statement is the first part of $\;A\cap C\;\subseteq\;\Q\;\subseteq\;A\cup C\;$, the set level version of $\;P\land Q\;\R\;(P\text{ if }Q\text{ else }R)\;\R\;P\lor Q\;$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}
A\cap C&=\big(A\cap(B\cup B')\big)\cap C\\
&=\big((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')\big)\cap C\\
&=(A\cap B\cap C)\cup(A\cap B'\cap C)\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
(A\cap C)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B'\cap C)&=(A\cap B\cap C)\cup(A\cap B'\cap C)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B'\cap C)\\
&=\big((A\cap B\cap C)\cup(A\cap B)\big)\cup\big((A\cap B'\cap C)\cup(B'\cap C)\big)\\
&=(A\cap B)\cup(B'\cap C)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Naïvely, in Zermelo set theory:

> **Axiom of extensionality:** A set $A$ is equal to $B$ if every element of $A$ is an element of $B$ (i.e. $A\subset B$) and vice versa
>   (i.e. $B\subset A$).

Regardless of the proof you choose to use, at some point, your argument will have to call upon the above axiom. Unfortunately (or fortunately?), there is no avoiding it. Your notion of "proving it algebraically" is therefore, in a sense, ill-posed.